# Python/Django 'WindowsPath' Type Error in Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I keep getting the 'TypeError' below when running a Django project in the virtual environment.
What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
  File "D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 190, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 287, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "D:\Studio\Python\REST\elections\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 13, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Here's the settings code for the Databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'` means you're dividing `BASE_DIR` by the string `db.sqlite3`, which doesn't make any sense. Use this instead:

```
'NAME': BASE_DIR + '/db.sqlite3',
```

and you should be all set. Alternatively, you can use:

```
'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
```

Obviously you would need to `import os` in your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the setting DATABASES - NAME expects a string, not a Path object.

In your settings try changing this line

'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',

to

'NAME': str(BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3'),